# Are all unicellular eukaryotic organisms protists?

Tags: cell-biology, taxonomy, eukaryotic-cells

I know that the Protists are in Domain Eukarya, and that some protists are unicellular. Are there any other eukaryotic group of creatures that are not protists that are unicellular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two other kingdoms contain unicellular organisms.

Some fungi, such as [yeasts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeast) are unicellular.

Many algal (Plantae) species are unicellular, including the spectacular *[Valonia ventricosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valonia_ventricosa)*, which is up to 5 cm (2 inches) in diameter. There is also a genus of seaweed *[Caulerpa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caulerpa)*, which is unicellular, though multi-nucleate that is thought to be the largest single-celled organism, being up to about 3 m (10 feet) long.

Comment: Not the kingdom decides, hence